# What names do files have when using sass --watch with directories?

Tags: sass

In the Sass manual, it says `sass --watch` takes 2 arguments: either input_file and output_file, or input_directory and output_directory.

You'll notice when watching files only, we get to explicitly specify what the name of our output file should be. However there's no reference to this when watching directories.

What names do the output files have when watching directories? If we have a file called name.scss, would the output just be name.css? Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Did you try watching the directory to see what happened?

Comment: Yes this is what I suspected from my investigation, but without knowing about partials there would be no way I would have known that it didn't compile files whose names begin with underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching a directory will compile all files not prefixed with an underscore as [name].css in the specified directory.  This cannot be changed.

You can instead use the underscore prefix to prevent compilation and include that file into a file with the name you *do* want.

- _file-with-name-i-dont-want.scss
- file-with-name-i-want.scss

Contents of file-with-name-i-want.scss:

```
@import "file-with-name-i-dont-want";
```